# reverse methods returning the object

Tags: javascript

The reverse method in javascript reverses an array in place:

```
let anArray = [0, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(anArray)
anArray.reverse()
console.log(anArray)
```

Output:

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 3, 2, 1, 0 ]
```

Yet, it also seems to return the reversed array itself (?):

```
let anArray = [0, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(anArray)
alsoAnArray = anArray.reverse()
console.log(anArray)
console.log(alsoAnArray)
```

Output:

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 3, 2, 1, 0 ]
[ 3, 2, 1, 0 ]
```

What is going on? I have never seen that a method working in place also returns the object it works on. Is this something that I have to expect a lot in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

> What is going on?

Nothing in particular, it's just that the method is defined that way. So is `sort`. If you want a copy, use `slice` with no arguments first (`const result = original.slice().reverse();`).

> I have never seen that a method working in place also returns the object it works on.

It's fairly common. For instance, it's not uncommon for an `add` method on a collection class to return the collection for chaining purposes (though sadly JavaScript's `Map.prototype.set` method doesn't do that).

> Is this something that I have to expect a lot in javascript?

`Array.prototype.sort` does the same thing. Depending on your interpretation of "working in place," so does `Set.prototype.add` (adds the thing, returns the set for chaining purposes).

Comment: The is technical term is [Method Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) and it exists to get some positive properties of functional programming languages in object-oriented programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

> The reverse() method reverses an array in place.

If you want to preserve the original array you need to copy the original array first. For the you can use `...`/ `Array.slice`